# Custom field date order

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom field called dead_date where i put the date like this dd-mm-yyyy. 
Now i'm calling it so i can order it by date like this:

- 01-03-2015
- 27-02-2015
- 14-12-2014

But what i've got is this:

- 01-03-2015
- 14-12-2014
- 27-02-2015

Down below you find my code

```
$args = array(
        'posts_per_page'   => 500,
        'offset'           => 0,
        'category'         => 1,
        'meta_key'         => 'dead_date',
        'orderby'          => 'meta_value',
        'order'            => 'DESC',
        'post_type'        => 'post',
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
        'suppress_filters' => true 
);

$posts_array = get_posts( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `meta_type` and a value of `'DATE'`.

```
$args = array(
        'posts_per_page'   => -1,       
        'category'         => 1,
        'meta_key'         => 'dead_date',
        'orderby'          => 'meta_value',
        'order'            => 'DESC',
        'post_type'        => 'post',
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
        'suppress_filters' => true,
        'meta_type'        => 'DATE'
);
$posts_array = get_posts( $args );
```

`get_posts` uses WP_Query, so you may be able to use the same parameters, and according to the [WP_Query documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters):

> 'meta_value' - Note that a 'meta_key=keyname' must also be present in
>   the query. Note also that the sorting will be alphabetical which is
>   fine for strings (i.e. words), but can be unexpected for numbers (e.g.
>   1, 3, 34, 4, 56, 6, etc, rather than 1, 3, 4, 6, 34, 56 as you might
>   naturally expect). Use 'meta_value_num' instead for numeric values.
>   You may also specify 'meta_type' if you want to cast the meta value as
>   a specific type. Possible values are 'NUMERIC', 'BINARY', 'CHAR',
>   'DATE', 'DATETIME', 'DECIMAL', 'SIGNED', 'TIME', 'UNSIGNED', same as
>   in '$meta_query'.

If it doesn't work, you may have to use `WP_Query` instead of `get_posts`.

Comment: I don't get it. What i'm supposed to change then?

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
        'posts_per_page'   => -1,       
        'category'         => 1,
        'meta_key'         => 'dead_date',
        'orderby'          => 'meta_value',
        'order'            => 'DESC',
        'post_type'        => 'post',
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
        'suppress_filters' => true 
);
$posts_array = get_posts( $args );
```

This might help you. Cheers!!

Comment: can you please remove  'order'            => 'DESC', and try for once?

Comment: If i do that it works but than it's ASC, but i changed my input to yyyy-mm-dd and then it worked. 
But thanks anyway!